# iOS SearchController Searchbar does not work after adding constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, autoresizingmask

I have an iOS project whereby the SearchController's SearchBar is added to the view as a subview:

```
let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 350.0, height: 45.0))
subView.addSubview((self.searchController.searchBar))
self.view.addSubview(subView)
```

As shown in the screenshot below, the searchbar is partially obscured by the navigation bar:

[image]

As such, I added the following constraint:

```
subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)])
```

The searchbar is now positioned correctly below the navigation bar as shown:

[image]

However, I'm now not able to click onto the searchbar to input any text. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try setting sufficient constraints on `subView`. You must always provide enough constraints to give a view a position and a size. You should also set sufficient constraints on the search bar to fit it inside `subView`. But why bother with `subView`? Does it have other things besides the search bar?

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks for your comment. I did as you suggested and added the searchbar directly to the view instead of using a subView. However, I'm now presented with another problem. When I clicked on the searchbar, it disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I resolved this at the end.

I still made use of a subView for the searchbar. But this time, instead of giving a fixed value for y, I used the heights of the safeArea and the navigation bar as shown:

```
 let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
 let safeheight = window?.safeAreaInsets.top
        
 let navHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
        
 let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: safeheight! + navHeight!, width: 350.0, height: 45.0))
 subView.addSubview((self.searchController.searchBar))
 self.view.addSubview(subView)
```

This time, the searchbar was positioned correctly and worked perfectly.